# Mix DISTINCT and UPPER keywords together

Tags: sql, oracle, select, distinct, uppercase

I have this query on Oracle 10:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NOME
FROM ICT.UTENTE
WHERE UPPER(nome) LIKE UPPER('MA%');
```

This works and get me something like:

```
MARIA LUISA
Mariano
MARIO
```

What I really would is to get each row in upper case, but I can't figure out a way to mix `DISTINCT` and `UPPER` keywords together. I have tried to replace first query line with any of this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(nome)   -- not a SELECTed expression
SELECT UPPER (DISTINCT nome)  -- missing expression
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER nome    -- upper: invalid identifier
SELECT UPPER DISTINCT nome    -- FROM keyword not found where expected
```

but I always got troubles! Is subquerying the only solution?

Comment: What errors in particular?

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(nome)` should work... what is the error? And which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Like Thomas mentioned `select distinct upper` should work, I don't think you need UPPER on constant values - `UPPER('MA%')`

Comment: is not a constant value but something from HTML form

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work.

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(nome)
```

Indeed it does work.  If you're getting this error ...

```
ORA-01791: not a SELECTed expression
```

...then you haven't posted the whole query.  Specifically you're not showing us the ORDER BY clause.  With a DISTINCT the attributes in the ORDER BY clause must match the projection.  So either you need to ...

```
ORDER BY upper(nome)
```

... or you can cheat and sort by position instead ...

```
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: Yes, I was hiding the order clause for brevity sake.

Answer (score 0):

In case your DBMS really doesn't support the mix of DISTINCT and UPPER (which would be very strange), you may try to use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT, like this:

```
SELECT UPPER(NOME)
FROM ICT.UTENTE
WHERE UPPER(nome) LIKE UPPER('MA%')
GROUP BY UPPER(NOME);
```

In case the LIKE implementation of your DBMS is case sensitive, there may also be a case-insensitive operator variant called "ILIKE", which could be used instead of LIKE with UPPER in the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT UPPER(NOME)
FROM ICT.UTENTE
WHERE nome ILIKE 'MA%'
GROUP BY UPPER(NOME);
```

It depends on the DBMS you are using...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Upper(NOME) as NOME
FROM ICT.UTENTE
```

OR

```
SELECT  Upper(NOME) as NOME
FROM ICT.UTENTE group by NOME
```